# Bowyer-Watson triangulates incorrectly when trying to implement circumcircle calculation for vertices at infinity

Tags: python, pygame

Quick primer on Bowyer-Watson:

```
function BowyerWatson (pointList)
      // pointList is a set of coordinates defining the points to be triangulated
      triangulation := empty triangle mesh data structure
      add super-triangle to triangulation // must be large enough to completely contain all the points in pointList
      for each point in pointList do // add all the points one at a time to the triangulation
         badTriangles := empty set
         for each triangle in triangulation do // first find all the triangles that are no longer valid due to the insertion
            if point is inside circumcircle of triangle
               add triangle to badTriangles
         polygon := empty set
         for each triangle in badTriangles do // find the boundary of the polygonal hole
            for each edge in triangle do
               if edge is not shared by any other triangles in badTriangles
                  add edge to polygon
         for each triangle in badTriangles do // remove them from the data structure
            remove triangle from triangulation
         for each edge in polygon do // re-triangulate the polygonal hole
            newTri := form a triangle from edge to point
            add newTri to triangulation
      for each triangle in triangulation // done inserting points, now clean up
         if triangle contains a vertex from original super-triangle
            remove triangle from triangulation
      return triangulation
```

This was implemented into python 3.7.2 and pygame 1.7~ with relative ease.

After this, I found [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36992359/11306106) on another post stating that most Bowyer-Watson algorithms lack calculations for vertices at infinity and implementations to overcome this:

> 1. Check if any of triangles vertices lies at infinity. In other words:
>      check if triangle is sharing some vertices with bounding triangle.
> 2. If it's sharing all three vertices: trivial.
> 3. If it's sharing zero vertices: classical approach - check if
>      distance from point to circumcenter is shorter than circumradius.
> 4. If it's sharing one vertex: check if point lies to the left/right of
>      line defined by the other two vertices. [one vertex in infinity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GvjJZ.png)
> 5. If it's sharing two vertices: check if point lies to the left/right
>      of line defined by these two vertices but shifted to the third
>      point. In other words: you take only the slope vector from line
>      between these shared vertices and shift it so that the line passes
>      through the third point. [two vertices in infinity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9JX3e.png)

Therefore, I created a new `Point()` class instead of the built-in `pygame.Vector2()`, with an added `isInfinite` boolean element.

For the `Triangle()` class, it takes in 3 `Point()` and sorts then into 2 lists: `finiteVertices` and `infiniteVertices` based on the `isInfinite` element in each `Point` and executes the procedure stated above depending on how many elements are in each list.

This would be great if it didn't turn my triangulation into spagetti.

My code is:

```
import pygame
import pygame.gfxdraw
import math
import random
pygame.init()


def Sign(value):
    if value < 0:
        return -1
    if value > 0:
        return 1
    if value == 0:
        return 0

def SideOfLineOfPoint(x1,y1,x2,y2,posX,posY):
    d = (posX-x1)*(y2-y1) - (posY-y1)*(x2-x1)
    return Sign(d)

def LineIsEqual(line1,line2): # Detect congruence of line, no matter which end is defined first
    if (line1[0] == line2[0] and line1[1] == line2[1]) or (line1[0] == line2[1] and line1[1] == line2[0]):
        return True
    return False


class Point:
    def __init__(self,x,y,isInfinite):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.isInfinite = isInfinite
    def distanceTo(self,other):
        return math.sqrt( (self.x-other.x)**2 + (self.y-other.y)**2 )

class Triangle:

    def __init__(self,a,b,c):
        self.vertices = [a,b,c] # a,b,c are vertices defining the triangle
        self.edges = [[a,b],
                      [b,c],
                      [c,a]] # Manually defining all edges of triangle ([])
        self.CalculateCircumcenter()
        self.infiniteVertices = []
        self.finiteVertices = []
        for vertex in self.vertices:
            if vertex.isInfinite:
                self.infiniteVertices.append(vertex)
            else:
                self.finiteVertices.append(vertex)

    def CalculateCircumcenter(self): # Copied from Delaunator page
        a = [self.vertices[0].x , self.vertices[0].y]
        b = [self.vertices[1].x , self.vertices[1].y]
        c = [self.vertices[2].x , self.vertices[2].y]
        ad = a[0] * a[0] + a[1] * a[1]
        bd = b[0] * b[0] + b[1] * b[1]
        cd = c[0] * c[0] + c[1] * c[1]
        D = 2 * (a[0] * (b[1] - c[1]) + b[0] * (c[1] - a[1]) + c[0] * (a[1] - b[1]))
        self.circumcenter = Point(1 / D * (ad * (b[1] - c[1]) + bd * (c[1] - a[1]) + cd * (a[1] - b[1])),
                                  1 / D * (ad * (c[0] - b[0]) + bd * (a[0] - c[0]) + cd * (b[0] - a[0])),
                                  False)

    def IsPointInCircumcircle(self,point):
        if len(self.infiniteVertices) == 3:
            return True # Any point is within the circumcircle if all therr vertices are infinite
        elif len(self.infiniteVertices) == 2: # If two infinite vertices: check if point lies to the left/right of line defined by these two vertices but shifted to the third point.
            x1 = self.finiteVertices[0].x
            y1 = self.finiteVertices[0].y
            x2 = self.infiniteVertices[0].x - self.infiniteVertices[1].x + x1
            y2 = self.infiniteVertices[0].y - self.infiniteVertices[1].y + y1
            sideOfLineOfVertex = SideOfLineOfPoint(x1,y1,x2,y2,point.x,point.y)
            sideOfLineOfPoint = SideOfLineOfPoint(x1,y1,x2,y2,self.infiniteVertices[0].x,self.infiniteVertices[0].x)
            if sideOfLineOfVertex == sideOfLineOfPoint:
                return False
            else:
                return True
        elif len(self.infiniteVertices) == 1: # If one infinite vertex: check if point lies to the left/right of line defined by the other two vertices.
            x1 = self.finiteVertices[0].x
            y1 = self.finiteVertices[0].y
            x2 = self.finiteVertices[1].x
            y2 = self.finiteVertices[1].y
            sideOfLineOfVertex = SideOfLineOfPoint(x1,y1,x2,y2,point.x,point.y)
            sideOfLineOfPoint = SideOfLineOfPoint(x1,y1,x2,y2,self.infiniteVertices[0].x,self.infiniteVertices[0].x)
            if sideOfLineOfVertex == sideOfLineOfPoint:
                return False
            else:
                return True
        elif len(self.infiniteVertices) == 0: # For triangle with finite vertices
            if self.vertices[0].distanceTo(self.circumcenter) > point.distanceTo(self.circumcenter):
                return True # If point is closer to circumcenter than any vertices, point is in circumcircle
            else:
                return False

    def HasVertex(self,point):
        if point in self.vertices:
            return True
        return False

    def Show(self,screen,colour):
        for edge in self.edges:
            pygame.draw.aaline(screen,colour,(edge[0].x,edge[0].y),(edge[1].x,edge[1].y))

class DelaunayTriangulation:

    def __init__(self,points,width,height):

        self.triangulation = [] # Create empty list

        self.superTriangleA = Point(-100,-100,True)
        self.superTriangleB = Point(2*width+100,-100,True)
        self.superTriangleC = Point(-100,2*height+100,True)
        superTriangle = Triangle(self.superTriangleA,self.superTriangleB,self.superTriangleC)
        self.triangulation.append(superTriangle) # Create super-triangle

        for point in points: # For every single point to be triangulated
            self.addPoint(point)

    def addPoint(self,point):

        invalidTriangles = [] # Invalid triangle list
        for triangle in self.triangulation: # For every existing triangle
            if triangle.IsPointInCircumcircle(point): # If new point is in the circumcenter of triangle
                invalidTriangles.append(triangle) # Triangle is invalid and added to invalid triangle list

        polygon = [] # List for remaining edges after removal of invalid triangles
        for triangle in invalidTriangles: # For every invalid triangle
            for triangleEdge in triangle.edges: # For each invalid triangle's edges
                isShared = False # Assume no edges are shared
                for other in invalidTriangles: # For every other invalid triangle
                    if triangle == other: # If both are the same triangle
                        continue
                    for otherEdge in other.edges: # For every edge in other triangle
                        if LineIsEqual(triangleEdge,otherEdge):
                            isShared = True # Congruent edges are shared
                if isShared == False: # Only append edges not shared by invalid triangles to polygon hole
                    polygon.append(triangleEdge)

        for triangle in invalidTriangles: # Remove invalid triangles
            self.triangulation.remove(triangle)
        for edge in polygon:
            newTriangle = Triangle(edge[0],edge[1],point) # Retriangulate based on edges of polygon hole and point
            self.triangulation.append(newTriangle)

    def Show(self,screen,colour):

        self.shownTriangulation = self.triangulation

        superTriangles = [] # List for triangles that are part of super-triangle
        for triangle in self.triangulation:
            if (triangle.HasVertex(self.superTriangleA) or triangle.HasVertex(self.superTriangleB) or triangle.HasVertex(self.superTriangleC)) and (triangle in self.triangulation):
                superTriangles.append(triangle) # Add triangles that have any super-triangle vertex
        for triangle in superTriangles:
            self.triangulation.remove(triangle) # Remove super-triangles

        for triangle in self.shownTriangulation:
            triangle.Show(screen,colour)


background = 20,40,100
red = 255,0,0
white = 255,255,255
width = int(500)
height = int(500)
amount = int(5)

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width,height))
screen.fill(background)

points = []
for i in range(amount):
    x = random.randint(1,width-1)
    y = random.randint(1,height-1)
    points.append(Point(x,y,False))

delaunay = DelaunayTriangulation(points,width,height)
delaunay.Show(screen,white)

pygame.display.update()
```

In my opinion, the functions that might be causing this problem would be `Triangle.IsPointInCircumcircle()` and `SideOfLineOfPoint()`, though it is also equally likely that the original algorithm isn't meant to support infinite-vertices calculation to begin with.

The code works if the whole infinite-vertices calculation is scrapped and normal circumcircle detection is used, though it would be a step backwards from my goal.

I hope someone could find any mistake in my code that would fix this or even just point me in the right direction to begin debugging this mess.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably the greatest improvement of performance can be gained by avoiding the expensive `math.sqrt` operation.

Instead of comparing the [Euclidean distances](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance) between the points, compare the square of the distance:

```py
class Point:

    # [...]

    def distanceToSquare(self,other):
        dx, dy = self.x-other.x, self.y-other.y
        return dx*dx + dy*dy
```

```py
class Triangle:

    # [...]

    def IsPointInCircumcircle(self,point):
        return (self.vertices[0].distanceToSquare(self.circumcenter) > 
                point.distanceToSquare(self.circumcenter))
```

---

Apart from that there are simple typos in your code. The `x` component of `infiniteVertices[0]` is passed twice to the method `SideOfLineOfPoint`, but the y component is missed (in both cases):

> ```py
> SideOfLineOfPoint(...,self.infiniteVertices[0].x,self.infiniteVertices[0].x)
> ```

Further the method `IsPointInCircumcircle` has to return `True`, in case when the points are on the same side. You do the opposite:

> ```py
> if sideOfLineOfVertex == sideOfLineOfPoint:
>    return False
> else:
>    return True
> ```

I recommend to reverse the order of the cases in the method `IsPointInCircumcircle`. The case `len(self.infiniteVertices) == 3` occur only once, when the 1st point is added. In compare `len(self.infinite Vertices) == 0` is the most common case, especially when the number of points increase.

See the result of the corrected method (for 20 random points):

[image]

```py
class Triangle:
    # [...]

    def IsPointInCircumcircle(self,point):
        if len(self.infiniteVertices) == 0: # For triangle with finite vertices
            if self.vertices[0].distanceToSquare(self.circumcenter) > point.distanceToSquare(self.circumcenter):
                return True # If point is closer to circumcenter than any vertices, point is in circumcircle
            else:
                return False

        elif len(self.infiniteVertices) == 1: # If one infinite vertex: check if point lies to the left/right of line defined by the other two vertices.
            x1 = self.finiteVertices[0].x
            y1 = self.finiteVertices[0].y
            x2 = self.finiteVertices[1].x
            y2 = self.finiteVertices[1].y
            sideOfLineOfVertex = SideOfLineOfPoint(x1,y1,x2,y2,point.x,point.y)
            sideOfLineOfPoint = SideOfLineOfPoint(x1,y1,x2,y2,self.infiniteVertices[0].x,self.infiniteVertices[0].y)
            if sideOfLineOfVertex == sideOfLineOfPoint:
                return True
            else:
                return False

        elif len(self.infiniteVertices) == 2: # If two infinite vertices: check if point lies to the left/right of line defined by these two vertices but shifted to the third point.
            x1 = self.finiteVertices[0].x
            y1 = self.finiteVertices[0].y
            x2 = self.infiniteVertices[0].x - self.infiniteVertices[1].x + x1
            y2 = self.infiniteVertices[0].y - self.infiniteVertices[1].y + y1
            sideOfLineOfVertex = SideOfLineOfPoint(x1,y1,x2,y2,point.x,point.y)
            sideOfLineOfPoint = SideOfLineOfPoint(x1,y1,x2,y2,self.infiniteVertices[0].x,self.infiniteVertices[0].y)
            if sideOfLineOfVertex == sideOfLineOfPoint:
                return True
            else:
                return False

        return True # Any point is within the circumcircle if all there vertices are infinite
```

Comment: tbh not surprised that i made the worst typo/logic error in IsPointInCircumcircle(). Thanks!    Edit: improving the speed with distanceToSquared is also quite a nice touch.